# Skryim: Is there an easy way to tell when you need a rested or well-rested bonus?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I know you can look at your active effects through the magic menu to tell if you have the rested or well-rested bonus, but I honestly have a hard time tracking how many game hours have passed before I need to get the well-rested bonus again.  Am I missing some notification somewhere that tells me I lost my bonus so I know when to rest again without having to track game time or frequently check the magic menu?

Comment: There's likely some documentation somewhere on the actual in-game time this takes, but I usually just head for a nap whenever one of the guards say, "You look tired, friend." Or you can seek out the "Lover's Stone" (+15%XP to all skills) and never take another nap ever again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are no notifications as such. You need to check the active effects and see whether you still have the bonus (it lasts for 8 hours). I feel 5% doesn't make much difference unless. 10% is still worthwhile. So whenever I'm near a bed that I own or inside some inn I just spend sometime sleeping.

(from [here](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Rested_Effect))

```
Level    Effect              Name    Bonus Attained.
 1       Rested              5%      Sleep in any bed.
 2       Well Rested         10%     Sleep in a bed you own or rent.
 3       Lover's Comfort     15%     Sleep in the house where your spouse lives.
```

You don't have to sleep for long durations. Even 1 hour of sleep is enough to give you the bonus.

(from [here](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Sleeping))

> Note:
>    - Unlike previous Elder Scrolls games, sleeping is no longer necessary    to level up. 
>    - You cannot sleep or wait when enemies are nearby. 
>    - You cannot wait while trespassing. You cannot sleep in an owned bed.
>    - Killing the owner of a bed will not remove the ownership.

Note2: Activating the lover's stone gives you a permanent 15% faster progress in all skills.

Comment: To add to this, usually when engaging in random conversations with people, they'll tend to mention something like "oh you don't look so good" or something to that effect.  That usually reminds me that I should find a bed and sleep in it.

Comment: @nageeb I usually get that when I have a disease.

Comment: Me, too.  In fact, I've predicted that I have some sort of disease 100% of the time every time someone has told me that.